# No `rc.local` in 16.10, so how can I add a command to set brightness on boot?

Tags: xubuntu, brightness, 16.10, sysfs

I previously solved the problem by adding a command:

```
echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

to `/etc/rc.local` on Ubuntu 14.04 . But there is no `/etc/rc.local` on Ubuntu 16.10 . I don't know how to solve it now. Is there a new script that replaces `rc.local` where I can enter my command?

Comment: You can actually enable `rc.local` again using service command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to make permanent changes to access points (they are not really files) in `/sys` is to use `sysfsutils` rather than `/etc/rc.local`. The package is not installed by default in 16.10,  so first do:

```
sudo apt install sysfsutils
```

now edit the file `/etc/sysfs.conf`, for example:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysfs.conf
```

and add this line to the end of it:

```
class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness = X
```

This will do the same as your `echo` command.

Comment: @ImsJoe great! Glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't know, `rc.local` is disabled by default in Ubuntu 16.10, because new versions of Ubuntu use [systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd). Thus make `rc.local` considered a service, but you can anytime turn on `rc.local` with service command:

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

Now that `rc.local` is enabled, you can use your old workaround, run following command to add desired brightness level to `/etc/rc.local` :

```
sudo sed -i '13i echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness  ' /etc/rc.local
```