# Able to disable Intel turbo boost by configuring /etc/rc.local on 14.04, but not on 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, startup, intel, turbo-boost

I want to disable Intel "turbo boost" on startup of my system. For reason of this, as well as my laptop details, please refer to my Stack Overflow thread: [Why can't my CPU retain peak performance in HPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36363613/4891738)

In an answer I made myself, I used the following line inside `/etc/rc.local`:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

This solution is partly motivated by this thread: [Disabling Intel Turbo Boost in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/619875/525956), and **was** working just as expected, before I upgrade my Ubuntu system from 14.04 to 16.04 in February. But after that it no longer works: the `no_turbo` value is still 0 and that line has no effect at all.

Of course, I could manually do the following later:

```
sudo su
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
exit
```

However, I can't remember doing this every time, and it is very discouraging when I realized that I had forgotten to do so and have to rerun a long benchmarking (like what I am doing now).

Is there an explanation why the same solution fails in 16.04? Or how can I achieve this automatically on startup?

---

Note I have other lines in `rc.local`, like for turning off Intel hyperthreading and setting backlight, they all work. It is just this particular line for "turbo boost" that fails. So the problem is not that `rc.local` is not run.

My machine has UEFI boot loader. Though there is an entry for the so-called legacy BIOS, there are few options there to set. Neither hyperthreading nor "turbo boost" can be configured.

---

In case someone wonders: the

```
systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

does not solve the issue.

Comment: I'm angry at whoever downvoted this to -1. I upvoted it back to 0. Nobody has written any reasons for downvoting.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work in rc.local if it works in an interactive shell, but have you tried [using sysfsutils?](https://askubuntu.com/a/846228/527764)